# Disproportionation Reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution

This is the problem I am trying to balance for redox:

$$\ce{HXeO4 -> XeO6^{4-} + Xe + O2}$$

It is supposed to be in a basic solution. However, my answer does not contain $\ce{OH-}$ on either side:

$$\ce{4HXeO4 -> XeO6^{4-} + 3Xe + 4O2 + 2H2O}$$

I am wondering if I had made a mistake or if it's ok for the reaction to not contain $\ce{OH-}$ ions.

Comment: The reaction is not balanced.  When there are charges you have to balance them too.  Try adding hydroxide ions ("basic solution") to the reactants and use them to balance the charges.  You'll need to rebalance the elements of course.

Comment: I thought this thing looked weird. The answer confirms that there is no neutral $\ce{HXeO4}$.

Answer (score 2):

The disproportionation reaction of xenates to perxenates in alkaline medium is given in the [Wikipedia article of xenon tetroxide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon_tetroxide?wprov=sfla1). Xenon tetroxide is made on the basis of disproportionatation reaction of xenate salts and further reaction of perxenate salts being  acidified forming unstable perxenic acid, hydrolysing to form xenon tetroxide.

> All syntheses(of xenon tetroxide) start from the perxenates, which are accessible from
>   the xenates through two methods. One is the disproportionation of
>   xenates to perxenates and xenon:
>
> $$\ce{2 HXeO4^− + 2 OH^− → XeO6^{4−} + Xe + O2 + 2 H2O}$$